# Removing dynamically added controls from WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a GroupBox in which I dynamically add controls into it. The controls I add are of two types `DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit` and `Windows.Forms.Label`
I am trying to remove these controls using the following

```
foreach (Control control in salesBox.Controls)
{
  control.Dispose(); 
  salesBox.Controls.Remove(control);
}
```

This is correctly removing the `TextEdit` controls but not the `Label` controls. The loop is not iterating through the `Label` controls.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to remove all controls from a controls collection is to call its `Clear` method:

```
salesBox.Controls.Clear();
```

---

Modifying collections can invalidate enumerators and yield unpredictable results or even throw an `InvalidOperationException`, depending on the collection type (see the "Remarks" section in [IEnumerable.GetEnumerator Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on MSDN). Since `foreach` uses an enumerator you should not alter the collection it is iterating.

Use a `for` statement, if you have to delete selectively and also iterate backwards, in order not to get wrong index values after removing items:

```
for (int i = salesBox.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Control c = salesBox.Controls[i];
    if (c is TextEdit || c is Label) {
        salesBox.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I liked reverse loop idea!

Comment: I added that on an earlier edit, but the revision check police didn't like it :(

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because you are modifying the collection you are iterating.  Calling the Dispose() method also removes a control from the parent's Control collection.  The side-effect is that you'll only dispose the even numbered controls.  Either of these two loops will get the job done:

```
while (salesBox.Controls.Count > 0) salesBox.Controls[0].Dispose();

for (int ix = salesBox.Controls.Count-1; ix >= 0; ix---) salesBox.Controls[ix].Dispose();
```

Or keep them on a panel and dispose the panel.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot alter the contents of the collection within the Foreach. You would need to do something like this I believe.

```
List<Control> toRemove = salesBox.Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList();

foreach(Control c in toRemove)
{
 salesBox.Controls.Remove(c);
 c.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You're right, forgot ControlCollection isn't IEnumerable<T> directly. Modified the answer to fix.

It does require System.Linq namespace

Answer (score 0):

`Foreach` can't iterate because the length of the `salesbox.Controls` changed. If you add or remove an item you'd better use `for`
You can do it by

```
   for(int i=0;i<salesBox.Controls.Count;i++)
    {      if(salesBox.Controls[i] is DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit) //your condition here
           { 
             salesBox.Controls.Remove(salesBox.Controls[i]);
             i--;
          }
    }
```

Comment: You would need to go backwards as i would end up being higher than the number of items in the collection, resulting in an exception

Comment: For some reason the reviewers don't like the edit, despite us discussing it here.

Got to earn those badges I suppose.